# how to capture event when right clicking on tab using winforms in powershell

Tags: powershell, winforms, tabs, event-handling, right-click

I want to fire an event when right clicking on a tab, not the contents displayed by the tab, but the [tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Gs3.png) themselves.

So far, I have tried using the selected event for the tabcontrol:

```
$maintab.add_selected({do something here})
```

this only fires when left clicking on the tabs

I also tried all of these, they don't seem to respond to clicks anywhere within the tabcontrol or the tabpages

```
$maintab.add_mouseUP({do something here})
$maintab.add_mouseDown({do something here})
$maintab.add_click({do something here})
$maintab.add_selecting({do something here})
```

I have also tried capturing the mouseUP event for the tabpages that have been added to the tabcontrol:

```
$tabpage.add_mouseUp({do something here})
```

This only works when clicking on the contents area below the tab, not the tabs themselves.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right with using the `MouseUP` event on the maintab control.

Below shows you how you can detect which of these tabs was clicked:

```
$maintab.Add_mouseUP({
    param($sender,$e)
    if ($e.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right) {
        # this part checks if on of the actual tabs is right-clicked
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $this.TabCount; $i++) {
            if ($this.GetTabRect($i).Contains($e.Location)) {
                # do something here
                Write-Host "Right-click on tab $($this.TabPages[$i].Text)"
                break
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: you know its really odd, I had a this line commented out in my program from previous testing $maintab.add_mouseUP({write-host object: $this.name event: $_.button}).  technically all I did was un-comment it and it works now.  I did do some updating and rolling back of VSC first, but I don't see how that would affect it!  either way, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!